# Why doesn't my python function work correctly when the sig_fig parameter is a multiple of four?

Tags: python

I made a function in python to round a number to a chosen number of significant figures. Strangely it only works when the sig_fig parameter is not a multiple of four. I would like an explanation.

```
def round_sig_fig(n, sig_fig = 3):
    x = 0
    if n == 0:
        n = 0
    elif abs(n) < 10**(sig_fig - 1):
        while abs(n) < 10**(sig_fig - 1):
            n *= 10
            x -= 1
    elif abs(n) > 10**(sig_fig):
        while abs(n) > 10**(sig_fig):
            n *= 0.1
            x += 1
    result = round(n) * (10**x)
    return result

x = 453.22599999999999
round_sig_fig(x, 7)
>>> 453.226
round_sig_fig(x, 10)
>>> 453.226
round_sig_fig(x, 8)
>>> 453.22600000000006
round_sig_fig(x, 12)
>>> 453.22600000000006
```

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with multiples of 4. It's just floating-point rounding error.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Just round the number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard computer foating point numbers are a bit of an approximation; for example, the number 0.1 (used in your calculation) cannot be represented exactly.

A few of possibilities:

- Rather than repeatedly multiplying, use the `round(x, ndigits)` form; the `ndigits` are the number of digits after the decimal point, but that's easily calculated. The `ndigits` can be negative to round to 10s, 100s, etc.

  `round(x, sig_fig - int(math.log(x, 10)) - 1)`
- If it's just to print out, and you'll always have digits after the decimal point, you can use the "number of decimal places" format.
- If it's for calculation, use the `Decimal` type rather than float; it behaves more like what we expect in terms of mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

`-1` on line 5 and 6 is the problem I think. If you remove it it works fine for all inputs defined.

Try this answer:

```
def round_sig_fig(n, sig_fig = 3):
    x = 0
    if n == 0:
        n = 0
    elif abs(n) < 10**(sig_fig ):
        while abs(n) < 10**(sig_fig ):
            n *= 10
            x -= 1
    elif abs(n) > 10**(sig_fig):
        while abs(n) > 10**(sig_fig):
            n *= 0.1
            x += 1
    result = round(n) * (10**x)
    return result

x = 453.22599999999999
print(round_sig_fig(x,8))
```